# How to loop through Rows and Column in SQL similar to DataTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a Table with 4 Columns & 4 Rows.

[image]

Columns -> A / B / C / D
Rows -> M / N / O / P

In a C# Datatable we can loop vertically and horizontally, and get the specific value for each cell.

Can the same thing be done in SQL - looping horizontally?
Example: Get all the values from `AN` till `CN`.
That would be `9`, `10` & `11`.

Edit:
I'm trying to basically create function, that requires `four` parameter.
R1, C1, R2, C2

By supplying that I will get a possible Quadrant - Could be a Rectangle or square. Which all the values sumed up.

Comment: `select ColA, ColB, ColC from MyTable where RowValue = 'N'`

Comment: We try not to loop in sql, its a set-based language.

Comment: What does it even mean to loop through them? Whats the bigger picture?

Comment: UNPIVOTing may get you there.

Comment: @Alex No this is not a homework, I wish it was :)

Comment: @DaleK I get a start point [A,N] and EndPoint [C,O].
From that, I need to make a rectangle and get Value for each.
So, the sum would be 9+10+11+5+6+7

Comment: Right, but in what context? An application? A query in SSMS? And with that start point what are you trying to return? SQL works in rows and columns, you select the columns you want to see and you select the rows you want to see them in. So why would you loop? Please try and explain more clearly as currently it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DaleK a) Query = Function in SQL
Return of a single summed value

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible, the question is whether it is worth doing it.

In your specific case the below code should do the trick.

```
CREATE TABLE #Square( RowID CHAR( 1 ), A INT, B INT, C INT, D INT )
INSERT INTO #Square
VALUES
( 'M', 13, 14, 15, 16 ),
( 'N', 09, 10, 11, 12 ),
( 'O', 05, 06, 07, 08 ),
( 'P', 01, 02, 03, 04 )

DECLARE @R1 CHAR( 1 ), @C1 CHAR( 1 ), @R2 CHAR( 1 ), @C2 CHAR( 1 )
SELECT @R1 = 'N', @C1 = 'A', @R2 = 'O', @C2 = 'C'
SELECT SUM( Num )
FROM
    ( SELECT *
    FROM #Square
    WHERE RowID BETWEEN @R1 AND @R2 ) AS a
UNPIVOT( Num FOR Col IN( A, B, C, D )) AS unpvt
WHERE Col BETWEEN @C1 AND @C2
```

Note that the above code relies on rows and especially columns having sequential names.

For arbitrary (but known in advance) column names, you would need to join the table to `sys.columns` to get ordinal positions and then use that.

Worst case scenario will be a dynamic query.